# Restful Api express postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I´m developing a rest full api with node and exrpess, my database is postgresql, I need to use the postgres package pg-promise.

I know that I need to connect my app with the database in the app.js file, but my question is, How I should use this connection in my endpoints.

I have routes and I am using controllers.

For example

app.js

```
//in this file, suppously I have to to the connection 
const db = pgp('postgres://john:pass123@localhost:5432/products');

app.use('/products', productsRoute);
```

products.js (route)

```
 router.get('/', ProductsController.get_all_products);
```

products.js (controller)

```
    exports.get_all_products = (req, res, next ) => {
        // Here i want to use de database connection to do the query to find all
        //products in the database
    }
```

How do I get access to the connection to do something like

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = $1', [true])
    .then(function(data) {
        // success;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // error;
    });
```

From the controller.

**Update**

Ok, I´m using now node-prostgres, pg. I saw is better, Thanks for the advice people.

I want to create one time de db instance, and call it anywhere, in specific in the controllers

Could I use app.local to save my client?, connect, do a query and then close it. Do this anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `pg-promise`.

If it helps, you can use [PostgreSQL client for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg). You can also use `async/await` with it.

Instead of a router, you can use Express middle-ware straightaway as follows.

```
//app.js:

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 1234

const db = require('./dbconnector')

//...omitted for brevity`
// 'db' is exported from a file such as 
// dbconnector.js.
app.get('/products', db.getProducts) 


//In dbconnector.js:
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'mydb',
  password: 'mypwd',
  port: 5432,
})

const getProducts = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id 
ASC', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
  }

// ...omitted for brevity

module.exports = {
 getProducts 

}
```

For modular design, please use a separate file (not `app.js/index.js/server.js`) for db connections as best practice and `require` that in your main `app.js`.

Here is [help](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) on `pg` module.

Comment: Could you explain me this please `please use a separate file (not app.js/index.js/server.js)`

Comment: Use a separate file such as `dbconnector.js` to handle connections to the db rather than handling connections, errors in the main file (`app.js`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to use it:

```
// mydb.js
async function someDbQuery() {
  let result;
  try {
    result = db.any('SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = $1', [true])
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
  return result;
}
module.exports = someDbQuery;

// in your controller after importing
const { someDbQuery } = require('./mydb.js')
exports.get_all_products = async (req, res, next ) => {
  // Here i want to use de database connection to do the query to find all
  //products in the database
  try {
    const result = await someDbQuery();
    // use result here
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Side note:

From the docs `pg-promise`

> Built on top of node-postgres

`node-postgres` now supports promise too.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything, pg-promise manages connections automatically. It will be allocated for the query and released right after. See [examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/examples).