# How to connect a Database to an Angular Web Application?

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, npm

I want to display and edit data from a existing PostgreSQL database in an Angular Web Application.
I am completely new to angular and stuff. 
I downloaded pg and express already.

After a look on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose
I figured I will need jugglingdb to connect the database to angular: https://npm.taobao.org/package/jugglingdb or https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-jugglingdb
-> more specific: Juggling-db with postgres: https://npm.taobao.org/package/jugglingdb-postgres

So I created a new file called postgres.js:

```
var Schema = require('jugglingdb').Schema;
var schema = new Schema('postgres', {
    database: 'mydatabase',
    username: 'myusername',
    host: 'myhostname', //I don't use the local user
    port: XXXX,
    password: s.password,
    ssl: false
});

var Model = schema.define('Model', {
    realNumber: {type: Number, dataType: 'float'}
  });
```

Then I tried it with the help of this answer: [Restful Api express postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609376/restful-api-express-postgres-database)
so I created a File called "dbconnector.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 1234

const db = require('./dbconnector')

// 'db' is exported from a file such as 
// dbconnector.js.
app.get('/things', db.getThings) 


//In dbconnector.js:
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'myuser',
  host: 'myhost',
  database: 'mydb',
  password: 'mypassword',
  port: 5432,
})

const getThings = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM public.regulation', 
    (error, results) => 
    {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
  }

module.exports = {
 getThings
}
```

I have searched, read and tried a lot of tutorials. 
But whatever I try - I just can't display the data from the database in the web applikation. 
Any ideas how I shall proceed? 
Do you know a complete guide (connecting the database and displaying the data?)
or do you have any links or tips?

*Edit*
Found this very useful Link to a download example: https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-6/angular-6-httpclient-postgresql-node-js-express-sequelize-crud-apis-post-get-put-delete

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An Angular application typically runs in the browser, while your database lives on a server. In simple terms, you usually connect them up by building a backend to your application that exposes any required data to consumers via an API.

It looks like you are using NodeJS for your backend from the links that you posted, so you could look into creating a RESTful API using [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express).

Comment: Yes - I figured that already - It's just that all the tutorials somehow couldn't help me. I still cannot display and edit data from the database with my web-application - any more specific ideas? Thank you already very much!

Comment: Well I would recommend breaking down the problem into backend (database + express.js application + API) and frontend (Angular application) and then building/debugging/testing those separately. I would recommend that you first build your backend and then debug it to make sure you are able to access your data as expected using Postman.(https://www.getpostman.com/), and then after that wire up your frontend to communicate with your API. If you aren't familiar with any of this then it might take a while, but just keep learning and going through tutorials and you will get there.

Comment: Alright - I will try again to get through the whole process again - thank you